# div with inline-block children doesn't display consistently with identical CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a div that contains several inline-block children:

[image]

The DOM looks like this:

[image]

It has the following CSS:

[image]

Each child has the following css:

[image]

If one **unchecks and rechecks** the `display: block` line marked above in the Chrome debugger, the div now looks like this:

[image]

Note that **there is now space between the labels**, and they are more readable. However, the CSS used to render this is presumably identical. Moreover, the div is actually still `display: block` when the specific selector's `display: block` is unchecked; it just obtains this from a less specific selector (in my case, the UA stylesheet for `div`).

I want the div to render the second way - is there a way to make this happen? How is the div supposed to be rendered, and where does the spacing between the `display: inline-block` elements come from?

**UPDATE**: This is probably caused by a weird interaction between Chrome's renderer and Meteor's Blaze rendering engine, and won't be seen except on highly dynamic pages.

Comment: @DanielLisik according to Chrome's `Edit as HTML` on the parent node, there is whitespace (several spaces and a newline) even before I poke the CSS. So could this be a rendering bug?

Comment: It could very well be something of that nature. I don't know if this will help, but what `display` value does the parent get when you uncheck `display:block`?

Comment: It's still `display: block`, from the UA stylesheet. The mystery deepens...

Comment: OMG! Hehe. Could you inspect the HTML on the switch (click on *Edit as HTML*) and keep an eye on what's happening in that section on the swtich?

Comment: What do you mean by the switch? I'm going to try and replicate this in a JSFiddle to see if anyone can figure out what is going on.

Comment: With switch I meant while you uncheck and then check the `display` property.

Comment: The HTML isn't changing. I've also tried to replicate at http://jsfiddle.net/psZ5p/ but no luck. My hunch is that the rendering glitch is caused by the labels being dynamically rendered by [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) and that spaces between them don't show up until the rendering engine is poked. I doubt I'll be able to reproduce this in a static context.

Comment: For me the spaces are there from the beginning, so what you suggested may be what's actually happening. It's very strange though.

Comment: It seems to work to remove all whitespace between the child `<div>` elements, and to manually insert a `&nbsp;` entity. Then there is no discrepancy between the two rendering methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of whitespace being evaluated. You can throw:

```
font-size: 0;
```

on the parent div and this will go away. Alternatively, adjust your markup to remove space between the list items.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is a way to do `font-size: 0` without overriding the font size on the children, which requires additional CSS to fix. Also, I would like the spaces to display.

Comment: You should then add margin: 0px 2px; to the pills

Comment: I don't agree with this solution. It makes all the text disappear and requires a bunch more CSS to fix. Additionally, whitespace exists in the first place which means the child divs should not be all squeezed together.

Comment: Don't use font-size: 0; Just add the margin.

Comment: then there will be huge sized spaces between the pills when rendered in some other browser (i.e. with whitespace evaluated properly). I am trying to figure out what the proper rendering of this is, and how to ensure it, rather than putting in a hack.

Comment: Then, normalize the spacing with font-size and reset your font-size on the pill itself